# Replacing Pandas or Numpy Nan with a None to use with MysqlDB

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, mysql-python

I am trying to write a Pandas dataframe (or can use a numpy array) to a mysql database using MysqlDB . MysqlDB doesn't seem understand 'nan' and my database throws out an error saying nan is not in the field list. I need to find a way to convert the 'nan' into a NoneType.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there no setting you can change in Pandas to make it return `None` for `NULL` instead of `nan`?

Answer (score 329, accepted):

@bogatron has it right, you can use [**`where`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html), it's worth noting that you can do this natively in pandas:

```
df1 = df.where(pd.notnull(df), None)
```

Note: this changes the dtype of **all columns** to `object`.

Example:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame([1, np.nan])

In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
    0
0   1
1 NaN

In [3]: df1 = df.where(pd.notnull(df), None)

In [4]: df1
Out[4]: 
      0
0     1
1  None
```

---

Note: what you cannot do recast the DataFrames `dtype` to allow all datatypes types, using [**`astype`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html), and then the DataFrame [**`fillna`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) method:

```
df1 = df.astype(object).replace(np.nan, 'None')
```

*Unfortunately neither this, nor using [**`replace`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html), works with `None` see [this (closed) issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/1972).*

---

As an aside, it's worth noting that for most use cases you don't need to replace NaN with None, see this question about [**the difference between NaN and None in pandas**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17534106/1240268).

However, in this specific case it seems you do (at least at the time of this answer).

Comment: see docs http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#where-and-masking

Comment: FWIW..this will also change the dtype of the columns to object, you probably don't care though

Comment: @Jeff Thanks for the link, weirdly I couldn't find it earlier! I figured it had to change the dtype to allow None, definitely worth mentioning!

Comment: useful to use before inserting with Django to avoid the `np.nan` being converted to string `"nan"`

Comment: Useful caveat. Makes sense to loop through only those columns that are already `dtype` of `object` and do it for those and handle other types differently as needed. Ideally, `fillna(None)` would be terrific.

Comment: An important use case is when converting to JSON. Not all languages support NaNs in JSON (such as PHP), so they need to be converted to None. This is something I've run into quite a bit as a data scientist.

Comment: Is this method still working? Currently only @EliadL 's answer below worked without errors for me, at least in pandas version `1.0.3` .

Comment: Using `df.where(pd.notnull(df), None)` no longer works in 1.3.0 - instead I found the next answer from @EliadL to still work fine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54403705/2407819

Comment: This only works for certain data types, example:
it changes NaN to None in string columns but not for Float type, that are not modified.
Going straight to numpy as said above worked for me 
`df = df.replace({np.nan: None})`

Comment: This works for me. It also preserves my column dtypes for columns that don't have NaNs in them (I'm using pandas 1.2.4)

Comment: Please update this code with ```replace(np.NaN, None)``` as the example code no longer works after 1.3.0 see https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/42423

Answer (score 349):

```
df = df.replace({np.nan: None})
```

Note: [For pandas versions <1.4,](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/35268) this changes the dtype of **all *affected* columns** to `object`.
To avoid that, use this syntax instead:

```
df = df.replace(np.nan, None)
```

Credit goes to this guy here on [this Github issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17494#issuecomment-328966324) and [Killian Huyghe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12094598/killian-huyghe)'s comment.

Comment: this is the best answer as you can use `df.replace({np.nan: None})` as a temp object

Comment: if the values in `df` are already `None` this answer will toggle them back to `np.nan`

Comment: @MaxSegal How is that? I haven't found this in `replace()` documentation. Can you refer me to where this is mentioned in the docs?

Comment: @AmmarAlyousfi `to = {np.nan: None}; assert df.replace(to).replace(to).equals(df)`

Comment: it does not toggle them back for me, nor does the documentation indicate it would.

Comment: I see the save behavior as @MaxSegal. `np.nan` is transformed into `None`, while `None` is transformed into `np.nan`

Comment: **for pandas versions <1.3.0** if the values in `df` are already `None` this answer will toggle them back to `np.nan`

Comment: I had the issue of them being toggled back on version >1.3.0. My column was categorical. When I switched it to object it worked again. Perhaps that may be the cause.

Comment: For pandas versions <1.4, there is a bug when using a dict in replace and your column dtypes may change unexpectedly, you should prefer this syntax instead: `df = df.replace(np.nan, None)`. See https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/35268

Answer (score 28):

You can replace `nan` with `None` in your numpy array:

```
>>> x = np.array([1, np.nan, 3])
>>> y = np.where(np.isnan(x), None, x)
>>> print y
[1.0 None 3.0]
>>> print type(y[1])
<type 'NoneType'>
```

Comment: The only potential concern is the change of `dtype`, `x.dtype` is `dtype('float64')` ,while `y.dtype` is `dtype('object')`.

Answer (score 26):

After stumbling around, this worked for me:

```
df = df.astype(object).where(pd.notnull(df),None)
```

Comment: This seems to required on newer versions of pandas. The `where` and `replace` methods both get converted back to `NaN` when applied to a `pd.Categorical` column

Answer (score 13):

replace `np.nan` with `None` is **accomplished differently across different version of pandas**:

```
if version.parse(pd.__version__) >= version.parse('1.3.0'):
    df = df.replace({np.nan: None})
else:
    df = df.where(pd.notnull(df), None)
```

this solves the issue that for pandas versions <1.3.0, if the values in `df` are already `None` then `df.replace({np.nan: None})` will toggle them back to `np.nan` **and vice versa**.

Answer (score 9):

Another addition: be careful when replacing multiples and converting the type of the column back from **object** to **float**. If you want to be certain that your `None`'s won't flip back to `np.NaN`'s apply @andy-hayden's suggestion with using `pd.where`.
Illustration of how replace can still go 'wrong':

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, np.NAN, np.inf]})

In [4]: df
Out[4]:
     a
0  1.0
1  NaN
2  inf

In [5]: df.replace({np.NAN: None})
Out[5]:
      a
0     1
1  None
2   inf

In [6]: df.replace({np.NAN: None, np.inf: None})
Out[6]:
     a
0  1.0
1  NaN
2  NaN

In [7]: df.where((pd.notnull(df)), None).replace({np.inf: None})
Out[7]:
     a
0  1.0
1  NaN
2  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for adding this. Going over the documentation again, I still can't understand this behavior. Anyway, this can be worked around by chaining yet another `.replace({np.nan: None})`

Comment: Yes, you could finish by adding another `replace({np.nan: None})`. My comment was added to point out the potential pitfall when replacing `np.nan`'s. The above certainly tripped me out for a bit!

Answer (score 8):

Just an addition to @Andy Hayden's answer:

Since [`DataFrame.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) is the opposite twin of [`DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html), they have the exactly same signature but with opposite meaning:

- `DataFrame.where` is useful for *Replacing values where the condition is **False**.*
- `DataFrame.mask` is used for *Replacing values where the condition is **True**.*

So in this question, using `df.mask(df.isna(), other=None, inplace=True)` might be more intuitive.

Answer (score 4):

Quite old, yet I stumbled upon the very same issue.
Try doing this:

```
df['col_replaced'] = df['col_with_npnans'].apply(lambda x: None if np.isnan(x) else x)
```

Comment: doesn't work if column data type is numeric because None just gets converted back into nan (pandas 0.23)

Answer (score 2):

I believe the cleanest way would be to make use of the `na_value` argument in the `pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy()` method ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html)):

> **na_value** : Any, optional
>
> The value to use for missing values. The default value depends on dtype  and the dtypes of the DataFrame columns.
>
> *New in version 1.1.0.*

You could e.g. convert to dictionaries with NaN's replaced by None using

```py
columns = df.columns.tolist()
dicts_with_nan_replaced = [
    dict(zip(columns, x))
    for x in df.to_numpy(na_value=None)
]
```

Comment: Your code keeps NaN as NaN, but you can fix it if you also pass `dtype=object`.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it is better to use this code. Note that np refers to the numpy:

```
df = df.fillna(np.nan).replace([np.nan], [None])
```

Comment: Why is `.fillna(np.nan)` needed here?

Comment: In my case replace doesn't work without it. It seems it's needed to convert na to a numpy object first, then use it in replace method.

Comment: By "na" which value are you referring to, exactly?

Comment: I meant Pandas NaN

Answer (score 1):

Convert numpy NaN to pandas NA before replacing with the where statement:

```
df = df.replace(np.NaN, pd.NA).where(df.notnull(), None)
```

Answer (score 1):

Astoundingly, None of the previous answers worked for me, so I had to do it for each column.

```
for column in df.columns:
            df[column] = df[column].where(pd.notnull(df[column]), None)
```

Comment: It would be useful if you can explain why the other answers did not work and how this one helps.

Comment: @YuvrajJaiswal I don't know why it didn't work, likewise I don't know exactly why my version works lol.
I suppose series.where is more straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a code block to review by chance?

Using *.loc*, pandas can access records based on logic conditions (filtering) and do action with them (when using =). Setting a *.loc* mask equal to some value will change the return array **inplace** (so be a touch careful here; I suggest test on a df copy prior to using in code block).

```py
df.loc[df['SomeColumn'].isna(), 'SomeColumn'] = None
```

The outer function is *df.loc[row_label, column_label] = None*. We're going to use a boolean mask for row_label by using the *.isna()* method to find 'NoneType' values in our column *SomeColumn*.

We'll use the *.isna()* method to return a boolean array of rows/records in column *SomeColumn* as our **row_label**: *df['SomeColumn'].isna()*. It will isolate all rows where *SomeColumn* has any of the 'NoneType' items pandas checks for with the *.isna()* method.

We'll use the column_label both when masking the dataframe for the row_label, and to identify the column we want to act on for the *.loc* mask.

Finally, we set the *.loc* mask equal to *None*, so the rows/records returned are changed to *None* based on the masked index.

Below are links to pandas documentation regarding *.loc* & *.isna()*.

References:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html

Answer (score 0):

After finding that neither the recommended answer, nor the alternate suggested worked for my application after a Pandas update to 1.3.2 I settled for safety with a brute force approach:

```
buf = df.to_json(orient='records')
recs = json.loads(buf)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option, that actually did the trick for me:

```
df = df.astype(object).replace(np.nan, None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing it by hand is the only way that is working for me right now.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45469744/14039999) answare from [@rodney cox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45469744/14039999) worked for me in almost every case.

The following code set all columns to `object` data type and then replace any null value to None. Setting the column data type to object is crucial because it prevents pandas to change the type further.

```py
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].astype(object)
    df.loc[df[col].isnull(), col] = None
```

*Warning*: This solution is not eficient, because it process columns that might not have np.nan values.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:
df["column"]=df["column"].apply(lambda x: None if pd.isnull(x) else x)

Answer (score -3):

This worked for me:

```
df = df.fillna(0)
```