# Use None instead of np.nan for null values in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame with mixed data types.  I would like to replace all null values with None (instead of default np.nan).  For some reason, this appears to be nearly impossible.

In reality my DataFrame is read in from a csv, but here is a simple DataFrame with mixed data types to illustrate my problem.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=[0], columns=range(5))
df.iloc[0] = [1, 'two', np.nan, 3, 4]
```

I can't do:

```
>>> df.fillna(None)
ValueError: must specify a fill method or value
```

nor:

```
>>> df[df.isnull()] = None
TypeError: Cannot do inplace boolean setting on mixed-types with a non np.nan value
```

nor:

```
>>> df.replace(np.nan, None)
TypeError: cannot replace [nan] with method pad on a DataFrame
```

I used to have a DataFrame with only string values, so I could do:

```
>>> df[df == ""] = None
```

which worked.  But now that I have mixed datatypes, it's a no go.

For various reasons about my code, it would be helpful to be able to use None as my null value.  Is there a way I can set the null values to None?  Or do I just have to go back through my other code and make sure I'm using np.isnan or pd.isnull everywhere?

Comment: `df[df.isnull()] = None` - works fine for me (pandas 0.18.1)

Answer (score 99, accepted):

[Use `pd.DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html)
Uses `df` value when condition is met, otherwise uses `None`

```
df.where(df.notnull(), None)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I tried so many different variations before seeing this. So far it's worked perfectly (I can't have numpy.nan's in my data because I'm copying some of it into SQL Alchemy objects and SQL Alchemy can't handle nan when writing to DB)

Comment: lifesaver. This is perfect especially when trying to insert NaN values to SQL!!!!

Comment: What is the solution for a single column?

Comment: Single column: `df['A'].where(df['A].notnull(), None)`

Comment: Caution that this method sets the `dtype` for all columns to `object`

Comment: Note you may need to manually cast to object (`astype(object)`). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70803926/4653485).

Comment: This is also very useful for writing from a dataframe to xlsxwriter (which requires Null, not NaN)!

Comment: For people wondering why it doesnt work, Using df.where(pd.notnull(df), None) no longer works in l.3 and later. Do `df = df.replace({float("NaN"): None})`.

Check answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162723/replacing-pandas-or-numpy-nan-with-a-none-to-use-with-mysqldb/54403705#54403705 and @apinanyogaratnam answer below.

Comment: Can confirm this doesnt/no longer works. @Sulphur comment works perfectly

Answer (score 7):

Expanding on the accpeted answer.. When you also need to catch `NaN` values within numeric dtype columns, you may need to change dtype to `object` first:

```
df.astype(object).where(df.notna(), None)
```

as per [original reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70803926/14775478) by @BENNY

Comment: Is it possible to only change the dtypes of columns originally with NaNs while maintaining the rest as before?

Comment: Sure. you can change the dtype of only a single column: `df['foo'].astype('float')`

Answer (score 4):

Found this helpful for replacing NaN values with None: `df.replace({pd.np.nan: None})`

Comment: Note that `pd.np.nan` is deprecated, but you can also just use `float("nan")` instead of importing numpy.