# Why does df.where() not replace all null values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, notnull

I have a dataframe with very mixed columns. I am trying to set all occurrences of `None` or `NaN` to `None`.

I am trying the answer to this question: [Use None instead of np.nan for null values in pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39279824/use-none-instead-of-np-nan-for-null-values-in-pandas-dataframe) But the accepted answer does not catch all null instances. Example:

```
my_array = ['1','2',None,4]
df = pd.DataFrame([my_array], columns=['Morning', 'Midday', 'Evening', 'Night'])
df = df.append({'Midday':'10'}, ignore_index=True)
```

which results in

```
  Morning Midday Evening  Night
0       1      2    None    4.0
1     NaN     10     NaN    NaN
```

Applying `df.where()` to find and replace all null vaules results in:

```
df.where(df.notnull(), None)

  Morning Midday Evening  Night
0       1      2    None    4.0
1    None     10    None    NaN
```

But I want output

```
  Morning Midday Evening  Night
0       1      2    None    4.0
1    None     10    None    None
```

What am I getting wrong, or is `df.where()` getting wrong?

Comment: The null values get treated differently because the dtype of `df['Night']` column is float, which can natively handle `NaN` values, whereas the integer columns can't natively handle `NaN`, so they get coerced to 'object'.

Comment: Retitled, because this question is less general than the title claimed to be. (Also, `df.append` got deprecated in pandas 1.4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the datatype to `object`

```
out = df.astype(object).where(df.notna(), None)
Out[392]: 
  Morning Midday Evening Night
0       1      2    None   4.0
1    None     10    None  None
```

Comment: Great answer, works for me. But please help me understand: Why is this? Both `df.where()` as well as `df.notna()` can be applied to numeric dtypes. Why the cast to `object`?

Comment: @KingOtto correct , the column type will impact the NaN and None change

Comment: Useful to explain why: the null values get treated differently because the dtype of `df['Night']` column is float, which can natively handle `NaN` values, whereas the integer columns can't natively handle `NaN`, so they get coerced to 'object'.