# Sending Pandas Dataframe with Int64 type to GCP Spanner INT64 column

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I am using Pandas Dataframes. I have a column from a CSV which is integers mixed in with nulls.

I am trying to convert this and insert it into Spanner in as generalizable a way as possible(so I can use the same code for future jobs), which reduces my ability to use sentinel variables. However, DFs cannot handle `NaN`s in a pure int column so you have to use `Int64`. When I try to insert this into Spanner I get an error that it is not an `int64` type, whereas pure Python `int`s do work. Is there an automatic way to convert `Int64` Pandas values to `int` values during the insert? Converting the column before inserting doesn't work, again, because of the null values. Is there another path around this?

Trying to convert from a Series goes like so:

```
>>>s2=pd.Series([3.0,5.0])
>>>s2
0    3.0
1    5.0
dtype: float64
>>>s1=pd.Series([3.0,None])
>>>s1
0    3.0
1    NaN
dtype: float64
>>>df = pd.DataFrame(data=[s1,s2], dtype=np.int64)
>>>df
   0    1
0  3  NaN
1  3  5.0
>>>df = pd.DataFrame(data={"nullable": s1, "nonnullable": s2}, dtype=np.int64)
```

this last command produces the error `ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to leave it as `NaN`(it turns out `NaN == 'nan'`). Then, at the very end, as I went to insert into the Spanner DB, I replaced all `NaN` with `None` in the DF. I used code from another SO answer: `df.replace({pd.np.nan: None})`. Spanner was looking at the `NaN` as a `'nan'` string and rejecting that for insertion into an Int64 column. `None` is treated as `NULL` and can get inserted into Spanner with no issue.

Comment: StackOverflow answer for replacing `nan` with `None`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54403705/101923

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to reproduce your issue but it seems everyone works as expected

Is it possible you have a non-nullable column that you are writing null values to?

## Retrieving the schema of a Spanner table

```
from google.cloud import spanner

client = spanner.Client()
database = client.instance('testinstance').database('testdatabase')
table_name='inttable'

query = f'''
SELECT
t.column_name,
t.spanner_type,
t.is_nullable
FROM
information_schema.columns AS t
WHERE
t.table_name = '{table_name}'
'''

with database.snapshot() as snapshot:
    print(list(snapshot.execute_sql(query)))
    # [['nonnullable', 'INT64', 'NO'], ['nullable', 'INT64', 'YES']]
```

## Inserting to spanner from a Pandas dataframe

```
from google.cloud import spanner

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

client = spanner.Client()
instance = client.instance('testinstance')
database = instance.database('testdatabase')


def insert(df):
    with database.batch() as batch:
        batch.insert(
            table='inttable',
            columns=(
                'nonnullable', 'nullable'),
            values=df.values.tolist()
        )

print("Succeeds in inserting int rows.")
d = {'nonnullable': [1, 2], 'nullable': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, dtype=np.int64)
insert(df)

print("Succeeds in inserting rows with None in nullable columns.")
d = {'nonnullable': [3, 4], 'nullable': [None, 6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, dtype=np.int64)
insert(df)

print("Fails (as expected) attempting to insert row with None in a nonnullable column fails as expected")
d = {'nonnullable': [5, None], 'nullable': [6, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, dtype=np.int64)
insert(df)
# Fails with "google.api_core.exceptions.FailedPrecondition: 400 nonnullable must not be NULL in table inttable."
```

Comment: I ran into a few problems which I put into the main post. Could you help me understand why this is the case with a Series when doing it with an array seems to work so well? Do I have to use an array?