# How to insert Null Value in database using teradatasql on a SMALLINT, Numeric overflow occurred during computation

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

So I use the `None` object to define null values in pandas dataframe. 
This is an example of the row in the dataframe with the `NaN` and `None`

```
27     XXX         None        41.0          NaN           1.0        50.0          NaN           1.0        71.0          3.0  0.9826382611          162.0             3.0  0.9952958893        MTD
```

When I insert `None` in dataframe it becomes `NaN` which then when inserted into a small integer field in **Teradata**, I get an insert error. How can I tell teradata to insert those `NaN` to null values in teradata using python?

> Numeric overflow occurred during computation.

In the below example, parameter 8 is `NaN`

```
Insert Exception in function insertDtframe, activated rollback: [Version 16.20.0.54] [Session 2258656] [Teradata SQL Driver] [Error 502] Batch row 3 bound parameter 8 type VARCHAR (448) differs from batch row 1 type FLOAT (480)
 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*teradataConnection).makeDriverErrorCode TeradataConnection.go:1074
 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*TeradataRows).validateBatchValues TeradataRows.go:947
 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.newTeradataRows TeradataRows.go:361
 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*teradataStatement).QueryContext TeradataStatement.go:122
 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*teradataConnection).QueryContext TeradataConnection.go:2036
 at database/sql.ctxDriverQuery ctxutil.go:48
 at database/sql.(*DB).queryDC.func1 sql.go:1464
 at database/sql.withLock sql.go:3032
 at database/sql.(*DB).queryDC sql.go:1459
 at database/sql.(*Conn).QueryContext sql.go:1701
 at main.goCreateRows goside.go:599
 at main._cgoexpwrap_e6e101e164fa_goCreateRows _cgo_gotypes.go:331
 at runtime.call64 asm_amd64.s:574
 at runtime.cgocallbackg1 cgocall.go:316
 at runtime.cgocallbackg cgocall.go:194
 at runtime.cgocallback_gofunc asm_amd64.s:826
 at runtime.goexit asm_amd64.s:2361
Completed Time: 2019-12-04 15:41:06.967610
```

Comment: Not Teradata-specific, more of an implementation difference between most database interfaces and *numpy*. For example, see [Replacing pandas or numpy NaN with None for MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162723/replacing-pandas-or-numpy-nan-with-a-none-to-use-with-mysqldb)

Comment: You helped. It works now. Thank you @Fred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Fred suggested, use the function `pandas.notnull` to replace `NaN` to `None`

Initially when you insert a `None` object to **pandas**, it replaces it with `NaN`. If you want to insert into a database you need to convert those `NaN` to `None`. This is because the database will think you are inserting a string, especially on integer data type fields. Below is the code to convert `NaN` to any specific value. In my scenario it should be `None`.

```
cNoneDtframe = parsedDtframe.where((pandas.notnull(parsedDtframe)), None)
```