# Set list field to None instead of str('nan') in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am saving a dataframe to sql using the following:

```
df.astype({...}).to_sql('search_raw', con=self.avails_conn, index='id')
```

I have a few list fields, and where the entry is `None`, instead of saving it as `NULL`, it saves it as the string `nan`. For example:
[image]

How can I save a list-field so that a null value (not `[]` but `None`) is saved as `NULL` in sql rather than `"nan"` ?

---

It seems that this approach doesn't work for a list field: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54403705/651174.

---

This might be a bit crude, but here's how I'm doing it now:

```
df['all_audio_languages'] = np.where(df['all_audio_languages'] == 'nan', None, df['all_audio_languages'])
```

Is there a better way to do this? The above approach seems pretty hackish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
df.astype({...}).to_sql('search_raw', con=self.avails_conn, index='id')
df = df.fillna(None)
```