# Fill NaN with Null pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to fill NaN with null (as we get in database). Can we do that?I have tried fillna("") but this gives empty string.

Please guide me.

Regards

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "null (as we get in database)". In Python, "null" is represented by NoneType, but NaN is a different data type specific to float values...

Comment: if a column is empty  in database we get null , i am expecting pandas to give null instead of Nan

Comment: since Null is equal to None in python, I want to replace NaN to None

Comment: Tried it, it was giving an error ValueError: Must specify a fill 'value' or 'method'.

Comment: Got it, turns out you can't use None as a filler value in fillna or replace. What happens when you run ``df.isnull()``? For the entries where you have NaN values, is it giving you True of False?

Comment: I am getting True

Comment: That means those values are already being interpreted as Null (by pandas definition at least). Can you specify where in your code or process these values are not being recognized as Null?

Comment: I am trying to insert these values into mongoDB and it is getting inserted as NaN, I want them to insert as null

Comment: Got it. Here are a few answers that might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162723/replacing-pandas-or-numpy-nan-with-a-none-to-use-with-mysqldb

Comment: Thank you, it worked like a charm