# How to bulk load to oracle table when column has missing data NaN

Tags: python, pandas, oracle

I'm trying to bulk load a dataframe into an oracle table. The following error occurs:

> DPY-3013: unsupported Python type str for database type DB_TYPE_NUMBER

No error occurs when the records are inserted one by one.

## Oracle table:

| Column_Name | Data_Type |
| --- | --- |
| MAKE | VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) |
| Model | VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) |
| Weight | NUMBER |
| Year | NUMBER(38,0) |

## Python Code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


data = {
  'Make': ['Honda', 'Toyota', 'BMW', 'Honda'],
  'Model': ['Civic', 'Camry', 'Caravan', 'Accord'],
  'Weight': [1020.25, np.NaN, 1235.37, 940.9],
  'Year': [2021, 2023, 2019, np.NaN]
}


df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
print(df.dtypes)

try:
    with db_connection.cursor() as cursor:
        
        cursor.executemany('insert into myTable values(:1, :2, :3, :4)', df.fillna('').values.tolist()) 
         
    db_connection.commit()
 
except Exception as error:
     print(error)
```

Please note the floats `NaN` must be inserted as `null` values to the table.

I attempted `df['Weight'].fillna(float('NaN'), inplace=True)`and  `df['Year'].fillna(float('NaN'), inplace=True)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing Pandas or Numpy Nan with a None to use with MysqlDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162723/replacing-pandas-or-numpy-nan-with-a-none-to-use-with-mysqldb)

Comment: I attempted replacing `NaN` with `None`, I received the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message says that you are trying to insert a string into column of type `NUMBER`

Instead of replacing `NaN` values with an empty string for all columns, you should handle each column separately based on its data type:

- Replace `NaN` string columns with empty strings
- Replace `NaN` in numeric columns with a sentinel value or a specific number

```
# Replace NaN in string columns with an empty string
df['Make'].fillna('', inplace=True)
df['Model'].fillna('', inplace=True)

# Replace NaN in numeric columns with a specific number or sentinel value
df['Weight'].fillna(-1, inplace=True)
df['Year'].fillna(-1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: I thought of that, however the empty numbers must be loaded as nulls. What you suggested would replace them with -1.